# Django CountryField, query by country

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a class similar to this:

```
    class Person(models.Model):
        name = CharField(max_length=255)
        citizenship = CountryField(multiple=True)
```

In this example a Person can have more than one citizenship.

```
Person.objects.create(name="Fred Flinstone", citizenship="US, CA")
```

I want to query for everyone who has a US citizenship, which would return Fred from above.  Is there a django-countries way to do this?  I suppose I could treat it like a CharField.  If I wanted to do something more complex like "is Person a citizen of US or GB", I was hoping there was a nicer way than a complex CharField query.

Comment: What package do you use? `django-countries`?

Comment: django-countries==7.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
 Person.objects.filter(citizenship__contains="US")
```

Also check out the django-countries code, especially tests, if my suggestion is not exactly what you are searching for, I am sure you will find answer there:

[Link to tests](https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries/blob/master/django_countries/tests/test_fields.py)

Comment: Thank you, I see in the tests that it matches more than just the string but full country names as well.  This is exactly what I was looking for.